# Spring batch - FlatFileItemReader - Sequence and Mapping of csv elements

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have my POJO as this:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

public class FileInfo {
    
    private String filepath;
    private String ignorestr1;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String employeeid;
    private String applicantid;
    private String createdate;
    private String startretdate;
    private String retlength;
    private String emporapplicant;
    
}
```

And my ItemReader is like this:

```
@Bean
    @StepScope
    @Qualifier("FileInfoItemReader")
    @DependsOn("partitioner")
    public FlatFileItemReader<FileInfo> FileInfoItemReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['fileName']}") String filename)
            throws MalformedURLException {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<FileInfo>().name("FileInfoItemReader").delimited().delimiter("|")
                .names(new String[] { "filepath", "ignorestr1", "firstname", "lastname", "employeeid", "applicantid", "createdate", "startretdate", "retlength", "emporapplicant" })
                .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<FileInfo>() {
                    {
                        setTargetType(FileInfo.class);
                    }
                }).resource(new UrlResource(filename)).build();
    }
```

**Update:**

My complete BatchConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchConfiguration.class);
    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private FlatFileItemReader<FileInfo> FileInfoItemReader;

    @Bean("partitioner")
    @StepScope
    public Partitioner partitioner() {
        log.info("In Partitioner");

        MultiResourcePartitioner partitioner = new MultiResourcePartitioner();
        ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        Resource[] resources = null;
        try {
            resources = resolver.getResources("*.csv");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        partitioner.setResources(resources);
        partitioner.partition(10);
        return partitioner;
    }

    @Bean
    public FileInfoItemProcessor processor() {
        return new FileInfoItemProcessor();
    }


    @Bean
    public FileInfoWriter<FileInfo> writer() {
        return new FileInfoWriter<FileInfo>();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job importUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step step1) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(listener)
                .flow(masterStep()).end().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<FileInfo, FileInfo>chunk(10).reader(FileInfoItemReader).processor(processor()).writer(writer())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(25);
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(25);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(25);
        taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return taskExecutor;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("masterStep")
    public Step masterStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("masterStep").partitioner("step1", partitioner()).step(step1())
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    @Qualifier("FileInfoItemReader")
    @DependsOn("partitioner")
    public FlatFileItemReader<FileInfo> FileInfoItemReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['fileName']}") String filename)
            throws MalformedURLException {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<FileInfo>().name("FileInfoItemReader").delimited().delimiter("|")
                .names(new String[] { "I", "can", "put", "literally", "anything", "here", "and", "it", "works", "just_fine" })
                .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<FileInfo>() {
                    {
                        setTargetType(FileInfo.class);
                    }
                }).resource(new UrlResource(filename)).build();
    }
}
```

**Doubt/Question:** My mapping follows the strict sequence in my FileInfo. If I switch the position of any of `private String....` in my POJO, the csv's row elements' mappings are messed up. Is that the expected behavior? If not, then what I am missing here? Or what is the correct way to make it POJO sequence independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper` uses reflection to map fields, so their declaration order in your class should not matter.

The order of fields that you declare in the array parameter in `.names()` corresponds to the order of columns in the input file, not to the declaration order in the POJO.

EDIT: Add sample

persons.csv

```
1,foo
2,bar
```

SO69224405.java

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.builder.FlatFileItemReaderBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SO69224405 {

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Person> itemReader() {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Person>()
                .name("personItemReader")
                .resource(new FileSystemResource("persons.csv"))
                .delimited()
                .names("id", "name") // with names("name", "id") the example fails
                .targetType(Person.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Person> itemWriter() {
        return items -> items.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps) {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .start(steps.get("step")
                        .<Person, Person>chunk(5)
                        .reader(itemReader())
                        .writer(itemWriter())
                        .build())
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SO69224405.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScript("/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql")
                .build();
    }

    public static class Person {
        // the declaration order of fields should not matter
        private String name;
        private int id;

        public Person() {
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Person{id=" + id + ", name='" + name + '\'' + '}';
        }
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>so69224405</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>so69224405</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.4</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

Comment: `.names()` array has no effect at all. No matter what Strings I put there. Am I missing something here? I am using spring boot 2.5.4.

Comment: It should, this is the order of column as they are in the file. I added a sample that shows that the order of fields in the pojo does not matter while it matters in the array of names passed to the mapper.

Comment: Hi Mahmoud thanks a lot for helping me out. Please take a look at my complete BatchConfig as Update in my initial post and see the `.names`, it just works fine. What is going wrong here. Looks like a interesting and serious issue here. Please let me know if you need any other details.

Comment: That's curious. Please provide a minimal complete example that I can download and run to be able to debug the case. That said, you should not call `partitioner.partition(10);`, this will be called by Spring Batch when running the partitioned step.

Comment: Hmmm... I found something interesting. Initially I had lombok. Then I removed lombok annotation and used old fashioned constructors, getters/setters, to string as per your sample. And it started worked perfectly fine as expected - as you mentioned. And now even though I switched back to lombok again, its still working. Weird stuff. Needless to mention I did a n number of clean/insall, rebuilds in between. Not too sure if this issue is related to Lombok. Anyways I am back on track Mahmoud. You are awesome. Accepting your answer for all your hard work and effort. Thanks a ton.

Comment: You are welcome. Good to see you solved your issue.